# OpenAuth without https

Tags: support, login

One of my computers is having problems and I can't use a https connection. I still want to log in to my Stack Overflow account, so is there any way for me to log in to OpenAuth using some service that does not use https? I can't use gmail, msn, or wordpress. I know it is not secure, but I do not mind doing it for a few times, and then I can unlink that unsecure ID from my account.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a proxy?  You might be able to find one that would use http with your computer, but use https in the underlying connection with SO/OpenAuth.

I haven't tried this, but it was the first thing to come to mind.  www.proxy.org